# Why do Database methods from node-sqlite3 not work when called in an exported function?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, ecmascript-6

I'm building an app using `node.js` using the `sqlite3` module to access the data store.  The problem I've been having is that when I run

```
node myapp.mjs
```

and `foo()` is called (in the `log.mjs` module), the `db.run(...)` statement in `foo()` doesn't execute although the console does output:

```
Logged foo!
```

There are no errors, no indication at all that the the statement has failed or succeeded save for the fact that there is no change in the database.  The entire line might as well be commented out.

Adding the line

```
foo();
```

to `log.mjs` works fine if I run the file directly:

```
node log.mjs
```

whether or not `foo` is exported.  Am I not grokking some import/export behaviour of ES6 modules or are there issues with the `sqlite3` module or something else?

File: `myapp.mjs`; the starting point.

```
import { foo } from "./bin/commands/log.mjs";

foo();

process.exit(0);
```

File: `log.mjs`; where the magic isn't happening.

```
import { sqlite3 } from "sqlite3";

sqlite3.verbose();

export function foo() {
   let db = new sqlite3.Database("./bin/db/test.db");
   db.run("insert into casefile (forum, fileno) values (1, 'LOG0000');");
   console.log("Logged foo!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlite3` Node package provides asynchronous API, in Node.js callback style (you provide the callback as the last argument of every method).

So when you fire `db.run()`, sqlite starts some processing, but as soon as it reaches an async operation under the hood, it parks in the event loop and the rest of your app continues its execution, i.e. `console.log()` followed by `process.exit()`, which kills your app, giving no chance to sqlite to continue its operations.

When you just run your `log.mjs` file directly, you do not kill the process, so Node waits for the async processes to complete.

The fact that you import/export this part of your app is not involved in this behaviour, only the killing of the process before the async operation completes.

You would very probably be interested in [`sqlite-async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-async) wrapper package, which converts `sqlite3` callback-style API into Promises, which you can then await. E.g. something like:

```js
await foo(); // Top-level await
process.exit(0);

async function foo() {
  const db = await Database.open("path/to/file");
  await db.run("statement");
  console.log("after some time");
}
```

Comment: +2 for the sqlite-async wrapper.